# How to pass parameter from express to angular?

Tags: angularjs, http, express

I am relatively new to AngularJS and ExpressJS. I have searched Google for answers but still stuck on the problem. Hence I come here to see if there would be any kind person who can help me out.

Here is the story: There is a web application, named A, with AngularJS 1.5.x for the front-end, ExpressJS 4.x, + NodeJS for the back-end. And there is another application B, who has sent the information to A's server via URL. So A's server now gets the info for parameters, and it needs to pass them to A's front-end.

SEE BELOW: The server-side code in Express - basically, the code gets two parameters from the URL named 'from' and 'to', then send them to the front-end.

```
app.get('/map/:from-:to', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.params);
});
```

SEE BELOW: The client-side code in Angular - If I want to get the parameter, I need to know the info: [FROM-TO] which are exactly the info that I need to retrieve...

```
 $http.get('/map/'+ [FROM-TO]).then(function (d) {
    console.log("MAP " + d);
  });
```

My question is: Is it possible to get the information from Express this way? (Feels wrong to me now). 
If it can't work this way, how can I pass the info 'from' and 'to' to the front-end? 
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: '/map/'+ [FROM-TO] This looks wrong. What is that? [FROM-TO]?

Comment: @yBrodsky  it is not code, it's a placeholder for the information I need to use to match the route in Express, while they are unknown in the client-side and need to be informed by the server-side

Comment: Then your question is not clear. You are doing a request to some url that takes some params, and returning those params. But you don't know the params in the first place. Its like the chicken or the egg story.

Comment: @yBrodsky Oh sorry for not mentioning that. Here it is:  suppose the application I have mentioned is A, and there is another application B, who has sent the information to A's server via URL. So A's server now gets the parameters, and it needs to pass them to A's front-end. That's the whole story.

Comment: Then the server needs to store those params somewhere so that when A wants to get them it can. And when A requests it, it won't need to have params in the url.

Comment: You mean file or database storage? Are there other ways to do so as the data is trivial...? @yBrodsky

Comment: you can store it in some variable defined outside the function.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks! @yBrodsky